# C# Mvc ajax baseUrl

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

So,

I have an application that uses MVC Areas. The route for the controller looks like

```
[Route("Settings/{something}")]
```

Then I have an Action

```
  [Route("suggest/{term}")]
  public ActionResult Suggest(string something, string term).
```

I try to call the Suggest action from javascript

```
var suggestUri = "suggest/";
$searchInput.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: suggestUri + request.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

From my point of view this ajax call url should be

```
 http://localhost:7311/Settings/firstValue/suggest/term
```

But the actual result is

```
 http://localhost:7311/Settings/suggest/term
```

It's missing the `{something}`

There is for sure something I do wrong, but I have no idea what.

LE: I've done some tests.

If I apply to my controller a different route like

[Route("Settings/{something}/a")]

The result is

```
 http://localhost:7311/Settings/firstValue/suggest/term
```

When it should be

```
http://localhost:7311/Settings/firstValue/a/suggest/term
```

Then i tried to do

```
[Route("Settings/{something}/a/b")]
```

The result is

```
 http://localhost:7311/Settings/firstValue/a/suggest/term
```

When it should be

```
http://localhost:7311/Settings/firstValue/a/b/suggest/term
```

It feels like the mvc always leaves out the last parameter from my controller. Any reason?

LE2 :

In Startup.cs the MapRoute looks like this

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
               name: "somethingBased",
               template: "{area:exists}/{somethingBased?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "home",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{application?}");

            });
```

Comment: Since you are passing the "something" value in your `ActionResult` I would suggest leaving your `controller route` the default route `[Route("[controller]")]`. And changing your `ActionResult` route to something like this : `[Route("Settings/{something}/suggest/{term}")]`. The reason being as it's the action result route that is passing the Something parameter not your Controller route. If not you would have to (or i would suggest you) change your MVC routing in the configuration.

Comment: I mocked up a quick test and mine is working just as you said yours _should_.  I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: How did you add the area's route mapping in Startup.cs?

Comment: @akasoggybunz I can't do that, all routes should follow "Settings/{something}" as Settings is the Area and something is an other component that defines where the settings are retrieved from. All controller actions should have this 2 parameters, then there is no reason to duplicate code and add them to the routes of the actions.

Comment: @nurdyguy I've edited with the MapRoutes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are rendering your javascript inside a Razor view, you can always use `@Url.Action` to calculate the URL rather than try to calculate it from javascript.

```
$searchInput.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: @Json.Serialize(Url.Action("Suggest", new { term = '$TERM$' })).replace('$TERM$', request.term),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

This is using `Url.Action("Suggest", new { term = '$TERM$' })` to calculate a template  to your MVC's routing server side, which returns `Settings/firstValue/suggest/$TERM$`.  Then `@Json.Serialize` converts that to javascript literal `"Settings/firstValue/suggest/$TERM$"`.

In javascript, you string.replace `$TERM$` with your dynamic value.  The javascript rendered by razor will look like this:

`url: "Settings/firstValue/suggest/$TERM$".replace("$TERM$", request.term)`

The advantage of this approach is that if you change your routing in MVC later, the client side code still works.

If you need to specify controller, area, or other route values that may not be inferred from the current context, `Url.Action` has plenty of overloads to handle that.

Comment: this anwser should be enough to solve the problem, i'm upvoting.

Comment: @Tim thank you for the answer, javascript is not in the same file with the razor, it's on a separate js file. I can't use Url.Action.

Comment: I will upvote the answer however, as some people might consider it useful.

Comment: @CiucaS What I usually do for this situation (having the javascript in js file instead of cshtml file) is I create a js variable in the cshtml file to hold the route and then just use that variable in the javascript file.  This way you take advantage of the `Url.Action` helper but also keep your javascript cleaner in its own file.